# Incorrect value when reading GPIOB_IDR register

Tags: c, arm, nucleo, stm32f0

I struggle with stm32f030r8 arm programming on atollic true studio ide.

I have some problem with reading correct data from idr register.

I make pull down PUPR register of GPIOB(0,1,2,3).

Other pins of GPIOB is output that i make with MODER register.

when i read idr data under loop every time i read F value but there is not any input.

Please help me to solve this problem [[image: You can see value that i read when debugging[1]]

[image: There is no any input It has to read 0x00]

```
#include "main.h"
int main(void)
{
 volatile static uint16_t PortDataInput=0x00;
 RCC->CR|=(uint32_t)0xF1; //set hsi clock source and with max speed
 GPIOB->PUPDR|=0xAA; //set firt 4 bit of gpiob as pull down
 GPIOB_RCC->AHBENR|=(1<<18); //enable gpiob clock source
 GPIOB->MODER|=0x55555500; //set firt 4 bit of gpiob as input
 GPIOB->OTYPER|=0x00000000; //set output pins of gpiob as push pull
 while (1)
 { 
 PortDataInput=GPIOB->IDR;
 PortDataInput&=0xF;
 }
```

Comment: What is `GPIOB_RCC`? Can you describe how the pins are connected? Is the photo relevant to the question?

Comment: Do not use magic numbers.

Comment: GPIOB_RCC is clock control register for gpiob.
AHBENR is register for enabling clock soruce for gpio ports.
PUPDR is register for choose pull up or pull down mode for gpio ports
MODER is register for choose gpio mode (input,output etc)
OTYPER for choose output type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
 Solution is that.I had to set all gpio registers after enabling peripheral clock.

```
#include "main.h"
int main(void)
{
 volatile static uint16_t PortDataInput=0x00;
 RCC->CR|=(uint32_t)0xF1; //set hsi clock source and with max speed
 GPIOB_RCC->AHBENR|=(1<<18); //enable gpiob clock source
 GPIOB->PUPDR|=0xAA; //set firt 4 bit of gpiob as pull down
 GPIOB->MODER|=0x55555500; //set firt 4 bit of gpiob as input
 GPIOB->OTYPER|=0x00000000; //set output pins of gpiob as push pull
while(1)
{
 PortDataInput=GPIOB->IDR;
 PortDataInput&=0xF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to set the gpio register before enabling peripheral clock. So you can't write to any of its registers.

Comment: I try it but result is same. I read 0xF again its changed to 0x0 after 5 cycle of loop and then again reads 0xF